# Scala Intellij suggests replacing size check with non empty, but why?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

```
if (cubeNames.size > 0) {
  //Do something
}
```

Intellij suggest this should be replaced by:

```
if (cubeNames.nonEmpty) {
  //Do something
}
```

Now function nonEmpty is defined as:

```
 def nonEmpty: Boolean = !isEmpty
```

Which is call to another function!

Is all this really necessary and in practicality, efficient?

Comment: Need to specify the type of `cubeNames` to clarify this question. `size` is constant on `Vector`, linear on `List`, and undefined on infinite sequences.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the compiler does inline things sometimes, so there may not be any overhead.

Comment: not if the function is not final, right?

Comment: I think it should be able to if the class is sealed.

Comment: In-depth explanation of all the IntelliJ collection inspections: https://pavelfatin.com/scala-collections-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.size` needs to go through the whole collection to determine its size, while `.isEmpty` simply needs to find one element to return `false`.

It probably won't matter too much for small collections (but you should still do it). However, for huge collections there will be a significant difference.

Even worse, if the collection is infinite (eg `val s:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: s`), then `.size` will never terminate, while `.isEmpty` will.

Comment: hmm I thought as the List grows it keeps its size (but probably that takes more memory)

Comment: @Dragonborn No, `List` specifically doesn't, because they are used pretty much everywhere and the size is needed quite rarely. Note that since it's a recursive type, the tail of a list would also store its size, and the tail of the tail, and so forth. This trade-off is made by all languages which share this concept of a list, as far as I know: Lisps, MLs, Erlang, Haskell, Scala, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that `read code` is much easier than `evaluate code`. That's why code `list.nonEmpty` may have only one meaning unlike `list.size > 0`.